# Angular ng-class does not work on invalid value in the field

Tags: angularjs

I have the an Angular code as below. When I input a character in the text box, it is supposed to apply ng-class "error" in the div(parent) tag. This does not work.

Any idea what the issue is?

Code:

```
<ng-form name="innerForm">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="value in values>
        <td>
          <div class="control-group input-append no-margin" ng-class="{error: innerForm.val_{{$index}}.$invalid}">
            <input  name="val_{{$index}}" id="val_{{$index}}" ng-model="value.val" ng-class="{edited: innerForm.val_{{$index}}}.$dirty"
          type="text" ng-pattern="/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/" ng-required />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-form>
```

Here is an example. When I enter a alphabet, it is supposed to through a background color around the text box. But it does not happen. http://embed.plnkr.co/cchyQYE69lnkjEqUNGGv/

Answer (score 0):

`ng-class` expect expression, it doesn't process `{{}}`(interpolation) directive, if in case you pass `{{expression}}`, then you will see an error. You have to correct your `ng-class` expression to below.

```
ng-class="{error: innerForm['val_'+ $index].$invalid}"
ng-class="{edited: innerForm['val_'+ $index].$dirty"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, this does not help. When I inspected, it shows ng-class="{error: innerForm['val_' + $index].$invalid}". The $index is not replaced with 0(actual value)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mixing Angular template `{{}}` with an already-expressionable syntax. Correct the usage of `ng-class` like this:

```
ng-class="{error: innerForm['val_' + $index].$invalid}"
```

and

```
ng-class="{edited: innerForm['val_' + $index].$dirty}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, this does not help. When I inspected, it shows  ng-class="{error: innerForm['val_' + $index].$invalid}". The $index is not replaced with 0(actual value)

Comment: @infinite_loop -- Please note that only the templates `{{}}` are replaced in HTML. The one in my solution are not replaced with `$index`'s value, but it should work. Do you have any other mean to define that it doesn't work?

Comment: When I enter an alphabet in the text box, the error is not shown by the div. However it shows error when the field is empty and it is in focus(This is working before this change). If you don't mind, can I ask you a working example in http://embed.plnkr.co/

Comment: Here is an example. When I enter a alphabet, it is supposed to through a background color around the text box. But it does not happen. http://embed.plnkr.co/cchyQYE69lnkjEqUNGGv/